# Xaml Design View Not Loaded in the Visual Studio Update1

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xaml

I have created a simple xaml project and design View Not Loaded in the Visual Studio Update1 as in diagram below.[image]

Answer (score 0):

This happens sometime. Simply click "Click Here to reload the designer". It always works.

Comment: Nope that wont work.